# ViewChild returns result, than becomes undefined (Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

My ViewChild gets properly logged on NgAfterViewInit but returns undefined after that.
When it get's initialized it logs properly, but then (in my case function on resize) logs undefined.

HTML:

```
<div class="hor-nav" #horNav>
<ul [hidden]="!navModule" class="top-nav-module">
  <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" class="hor-nav-item" #navItem>
    <a>
      ...Some link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
@ViewChild('horNav', {static: false}) horNav: ElementRef; // tried with static: true too


 ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('HOR NAV', this.horNav)   // This works just fine: HOR NAV ElementRef {nativeElement: div.hor-nav}
}



ngOnInit() {
   window.addEventListener('resize',  this.calculateNavBarWidth);
}

public calculateNavBarWidth() {
  console.log('Offset Width: ', this.horNav) // This returns undefined
}
```

Comment: What if you try with `{static: true}` ?

Comment: I tried already, not working

Comment: The context of `this` is different in the event listener. You could e.g. try to pass `this.calculateNavBarWidth.bind(this)` or `() => this.calculateNavBarWidth()` to the event listener.

Comment: Hey @StefanK, yes, you are right. I figured it out on my own (to use callback, not that this has another context), and then I saw your answer. So I learned from you.  You are absolutely right. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. it was the event Listener. This works now:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',  () => this.calculateNavBarWidth());
```

Comment: you can use rxjs operator fromEvent: `fromEvent(window,'resize').subscribe(res=>{..})` -don't forget unsubscribe- This allow you use, e.g. `pipe(debounceTime(200))` to only perform the operation each 200 miliseconds.